# Error C2065: 'С7' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++

Непонятная ошибка. Компилятор жалуется на операнд.

```
{
    int C7 = 7, C5 = 5, C3 = 3;

    if (line == 3) {
        C3 = C3 - quantity;

        cout << C7 << "     ";
        for (int j = 1; j <= C7; j++)
            cout << "| ";
        cout << endl;

        cout << C5 << "     ";
        for (int k = 1; k <= C5; k++)
            cout << "| ";
        cout << endl;

        cout << C3 << "     ";
        for (int l = 1; l <= C3; l++)
            cout << "| ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

cout << "Now my course, Gamer!  " << endl << endl;

while ((C7 != 0) && (С7 ^ C5 ^ C3 != 0))        // <-- вот тут **ТОЛЬКО** на C7 жалуется
{
    C7--;
}
```

Хотя я его наверху очень много раз использую и никаких проблем. С чего вдруг он начал ругаться на него? Никак не могу понять. Говорит, я не знаю такое.

Comment: по Вашему коду и не видно, что такое С7 - я бы тоже жаловался.

Comment: На мой взгляд, для полноты вопроса, не хватает кода, где объявляется C7, а также самого текста ошибки, которую выдаёт компилятор.

Comment: @Kremchik @KoVadim обновил код. Ошибка: error C2065: 'С7' : undeclared identifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А там точно си7, а не эс7?

Поиск Ctrl+f дает ясно понять, что там русская буква "Эс"

Comment: Благодарю!

Comment: На мой взгляд, здесь есть дополнительная проблема, которая может потом всплыть. Дело в том, что C7 объявлен внутри пары фигурных скобок и, следовательно, область определения у него именно этот блок кода (и вложенные в него). И поэтому в блоке с `while` идентификатор C7 должен быть недоступен.

Например,

     {
       int x = 10;
       if (blablabla)
       {
          int A;
          int x = 0;
          // здесь у нас A доступно
          ...
       }
       A = 10; // ошибка: нет декларации «A» в этой области видимости
       // чему равно x? 10!
     }